# call the method AddNewtonsoftJson() in particular class/controller level

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using  the code below and working fine (reading the Json data).

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Concern is I am changing the code for one API. due to these changes there shouldn't be any impact to other API.

So is there any way to call the method .AddNewtonsoftJson() in particular class/controller level  ?

I don't want to call .AddNewtonsoftJson()  in setatup.cs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of the JSON serializer is global for the whole ASP.NET Core application. It is not possible to change this just on a per-controller or per-action level.

What you can do however would be to manually parse the JSON in the special case from the request body.

I would generally suggest to reconsider if you really need this distinction though: If you really need Newtonsoft.Json functionality in your application, then it might make sense to just switch to it completely. The standard System.Text.Json serializer does not have any particular feature that Newtonsoft.Json could not also fulfill. So maybe just switching to it by default and configuring it properly is enough for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much use to add just services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
It makes sense if you need to add some options to it. For example I am using for API

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Comment: That is not completely true. For example `Json.NET` attributes wan't work for `System.Text.Json`.